# php ,use getmypid() get pid,but posix_kill expects exactly 2 parameters

Tags: php, process, pid, kill

I use `getmypid()` get pid,next use `posix_kill()` to kill this process.

```
$result = parse_url($result);
$pid = getmypid();
echo $pid.PHP_EOL;
posix_kill($pid，SIGTERM);
```

5684

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: pid，SIGTERM in /home/python/weixin.php on line 127
PHP Warning:  posix_kill() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/python/weixin.php on line 127

Comment: You have a strange character instead of a comma in the last line of your code between `$pid` and `SIGTERM`. The line should be `posix_kill($pid, SIGTERM);`

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ?

Comment: @MichaelGEDION: Does it matter in regard to the OP's problem?

Comment: Yes i remember someone saying having some issues depending on the operator have a look here.  http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn47re977.html

Comment: have a look here also : https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1966727-xampp-and-posix_getpid-issues, if it can help you...

Comment: @MichaelGEDION: Actually if he used Windows, the error would be _Call to undefined function posix_kill()_. In his case it really is the _wrong_ comma character in the last line of the code - PHP treats it as a part of variable name, so it complains about getting one parameter instead of two...

Comment: @MichaelGEDION use linux.